# How can I stub a function's block with OCMock to return an incrementing value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ocmock

The documentation for OCMock is great and clear. I have my particular class level function stubbed. It's for a request, and looks something like this:

```
OCMStub([self.mockApiManager 
    requestToURL:[OCMArg any] 
    method:[OCMArg any] 
    keypath:[OCMArg any] 
    parameters:[OCMArg any] 
    objectClass:[OCMArg any] 
    shouldRetry:NO 
    retryBlock:nil 
    withCompletionBlock:([OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:@(1), @[@(apiRequestCount)], requestOperation, [[NSError alloc] init], @(0), nil])])._andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation) {

        apiRequestCount++;
});
```

The part that I'm interested in is `[OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:@(1), @[@(apiRequestCount)], requestOperation, [[NSError alloc] init], @(0), nil]`. Particularly where I pass in apiRequestCount.

apiRequestCount is a static int on my test class. What I desire is to pass back an incremented value everytime the `-requestToURL:metho...` function is called/stubbed. So call it once, and it returns 0. Call it a second time, it returns 1. Etc.

However, despite this function getting stubbed 3 times, I get a 0 for the invokeBlockWithArgs. Can anyone think of a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

At the point when the stub is created and the `invokeBlockWithArgs` method is called on `OCMArg`, all the arguments (including the `apiRequestCount`) are taken and kept in an object behind the scenes. Further updates to `apiRequestCount` do not update that internal state and therefore the block is invoked with the same value that was originally provided.

That said, the `invokeBlock` methods are just for convenience. In your case you could pass `[OCMArg any]` for the block parameter to make sure the stub matches. Then, in the block you pass to `andDo`, you can pull out the completion handler block from the `NSInvocation`, and invoke it with the right value.